# Cannot read property '1' of null on my WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am running a new plugin on a client's WooCommerce/WordPress webshop, but it isn't working as supposed. The browser console is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.success (yith-wcp-frontend.min.js:1)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
```

I have 'pretty printed' that error, which will give me the proper lines:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.success (yith-wcp-frontend.min.js:formatted:206)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at y (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
```

This is what line 206 looks like:

[image: Line 206]
I've never really understood these 'Cannot read property '1' of null' errors, especially this one. Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

This is a link to the specific page: http://wqd.nl/3IFd

The error pops up when selecting something in the select list below 'Kleurkeuze'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Match returns null if there are no matches.  So it is throwing an error because you are trying to do an index off of null.  You should check that the element is an array, and has atleast 2 elements, before you try to access it with [1].

Comment: To rephrase, `i.html.match()` is returning `null` here.

Comment: @plushyObject how is hat a rephrase?

Comment: You took a paragraph to explain that the variable is returning `null`, bud.

Comment: Where else in the image above is "match" being used?  And if you are arguing that fully explaining an issue is a bad thing, well ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A website by developers, for developers, intended to solve developer problems.

Comment: I'm sure you know all about developer problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info Taplar. Fully explaining is not a bad thing, I now finally understand this error. I've seen it many times, just never figured out what was exactly wrong. Now I do :-)

As for this case: YITH has sorted it out for as it appeared to be an issue in their plugin. For those facing the same error: they'll be sending out an update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating YITH Composite Products plugin that you are using. I wonder if it has been resolved, and you are just using an incompatible version of WordPress, WooCommerce, or Yith.

Comment: It appeared to be a serious glitch in Yith's plugin. They've sorted it out for me, and will send out an update to all other customers asap.